# Supported devices filter in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I am going to publish an Android game to the Google Play Store, and I would like to post it only for powerful enough devices, which can run it smoothly. I am not registered yet, so I don't know how exactly the "publishing process" looks like - can you give me a hint? Is it a simple filter, in which I select all the devices I want to, and the users of the rest won't be able to find my game on the Store?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of tutorials where you can find this answer:

1) [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wN3JTIZXfk)

2) [Android](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#understand-publishing)

3) [Google](https://www.google.lv/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASRM_enLV571LV571&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20app%20publish%20tutorial)

Press any one of them and you will get your answer.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Google Play has a device limitation feature dedicated to that. 
By default, your app is open to all devices. This feature allows you to exclude devices by Manufacturer and Model.